# unicodeKeyboard does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, android, appium, appium-android

In my automatic tests, which are run using the appium and use real devices on testObject, there is an entry in the Cyrillic text field. In the capabilites, I add `unicodeKeyboard: true` and the `language: ‘ru’`. But the input does not work as expected. Example: instead of the `“кириллица”` text, something like `“&VDoEARA…”` is entered, etc. What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to fix this?

My caps:

```
deviceName: “Motorola Moto X”,
platformVersion: ‘4’,
platformName: “Android”,
language: “ru”,
unicodeKeyboard: true,
name: “Motorola Moto X”,
autoGrantPermissions: “true”,
gpsEnabled: “true”,
fullReset: false,
testobject_api_key: ‘here_is_my_key’
```

Parts of code:

```
return await element.keys(my_data);
```

I tried also use `type()` and `sendKeys()` methods, same effect.
I new in this, can someone help me please!

Comment: You need to set your keyboard input language same as the language in which you are typing the test

Comment: Appium Unicode Keyboard haven't input language settings on virtual keyboard.

Comment: Appium Unicode Keyboard haven't input language settings on virtual keyboard. Also it seems like encoded to Modified UTF-7 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501) text can't recode to Unicode, as says here: https://github.com/appium/io.appium.android.ime.
It does not works only on our app. With other app, e.g. Google Maps, unicode keyboard works well.
May be it our app trouble?